# open an oracle conn without tnsnames.ora

Tags: oracle, asp-classic

i have an old asp application running on oracle 9g and im using a **OracleInProcServer.XOraSession** object to connect with the database

```
Set OraSession = Server.CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XOraSession") 
Set OraBanco   = OraSession.DbOpenDatabase("ORADB01","Username/Password",cint(0))
```

so, i have this **ORADB01** registered on my tnsnames.ora

now lets say i need to open a connection with a database which i dont have registered on my tnsnames.ora... is there any way to open the connection using **OracleInProcServer.XOraSession**?

Answer (score 2):

Not tested but worth a try:

```
Set OraBanco = OraSession.DbOpenDatabase("YourServerName:1521/ORADB01","User/Pass",cint(0))
```

At least this works for linking a Oracle database to a SQL Server.

It doesn't apply for your XOraSession but you can even put the whole connection info into your ODBC connection string:

```
Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Password=***;User ID=username;Data Source="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
    (HOST=YourDatabaseServer)(PORT=1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME = ORADB01)))"
```

Comment: i tried that out and unfortunately it didn't work. i can do something similar when using a `ADODB.Connection`. if i have the connection on my tnsnames.ora i can open the connection like that: `objConn.Open "DSN=oradb01;Uid=user;Pwd=pass;"`. **but**, if its not on my tnsnames i could open the connection this way: `objConn.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myhost.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=oradb01.mydomain.com))); uid=user;pwd=pass;"`

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't give you a real solution. It looks like you'll be tied to using a tnsnames.ora when connecting your XOraSession.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and your suggestion did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You must have some kind of Oracle Client available and installed and accessible on your machine. you can open some connection with oracle using `//127.0.0.1:1521/XE` since this is Oracle XE not 9i, you are using ASP the better idea would be to

Either define ODBC connection, at Machine Level or use DNS file
and you must have oracle client available on your ASP server.

or if your asp server and machine are same you may be able to use `IPC` connection with server

i have done this with 10G, and  XE and it works fine you should check may work for you on 9i.

**i am not aware of 9G** it was 9i i think.